# html css code to print preview two tables side by side

Tags: html, css

i am displaying data in my page...like below image.

[image]

but when i click print preview from browser...this display print like below image..

i need to display both tables side by side like above image on print preview..plz help me...

[image]

below is my code...

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
table, td  { border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 15px; color: #000000; text-align: center; }

table.pos_fixed1 { float:left; top:30px; margin-left:120px; }

table.pos_fixed2 {  float:right; top:30px; margin-right:120px; }

</style>


<table  border="1px solid #666" summary="" width="40%" class="pos_fixed1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>

<table  border="1px solid #666" summary="" width="40%" class="pos_fixed2">
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
<tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have a look at `@media print {`, i.e. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `media="all"`
2. Reduce the width of both tables to 30%

[image]

```html
<style type="text/css" media="all">
  table,
  td {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
  }
  table.pos_fixed1 {
    float: left;
    top: 30px;
    margin-left: 120px;
  }
  table.pos_fixed2 {
    float: right;
    top: 30px;
    margin-right: 120px;
  }
</style>


<table border="1px solid #666" summary="" width="30%" class="pos_fixed1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1px solid #666" summary="" width="30%" class="pos_fixed2">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the `media="screen"` from the `style` element to `media="all"` so your styles apply to all media types, including **print**. With a *print media query* `@media print { /* print styles */ }` you can target just the print media type and adjust your styles for it.

Here you have the [w3c-spec for Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
  table, td {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .pos_fixed1 {
    float: left;
    top: 30px;
    margin-left: 120px;
  }

  .pos_fixed2 {
    float: right;
    top: 30px;
    margin-right: 120px;
  }

  @media print {
    .pos_fixed1,
    .pos_fixed2 {
      margin: 0;
      width: 50%;
    }
  }

</style>
```